# How to add resource files during build on J2ee (eclipse + jboss)

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jboss, build

i'm trying to run a web servlet project in eclipse 3.4 using jboss 4.2.2 as my web server. im using the wtp plugin and everything looks good (can run and debug).

but some of the files/resources are not included on the war file.

in my "WebContent/WEB-INF" folder, i have "properries", "config", and "lib" folders. but it seems like when i build and publish the project, only "config" and "lib" folders are included.

how can i include the "properties" file during build?

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Building > Output Folder* and check if `*.properties` is **not** been specified in the *Filtered Resources*. It would otherwise lead to them being skipped during build.